# What stores sell bacon in malaysia?

Tags: food-and-drink, malaysia

My wife and I moved to Malaysia for work few months ago and she loves bacon.I know its a country with a majority of Islamic followers but I have seen bacon in hotels which I makes me wonder if it is available to purchase here. I have looked in Tesco,Aeon and Giant but couldn't find it there. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pork products are generally available in the non-halal section of many of the supermarkets in Kuala Lumpur, as well as in non-halal speciality shops and wet markets.

A quick Google returned [AA Meat Shop](http://www.aameatshop.com.my/ham.html) with a whole assortment of pork products, including bacon (streaky and back), and has  [four Kuala Lumpur outlets](http://www.aameatshop.com.my/kl_branch.html).

Another, [Orient Fresh Deli](http://www.orientfreshdeli.com/our-products/), also has streaky and back bacon, along with lots of other pork products (ham, sausage, cold cuts). It has a shop at 9 Jalan Camar, Kepong Baru, KL... called Mr. Bacon !